# I am having an Error in creating Pivot using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot using below code, however I am receiving error,

> "Invalid Procedure call or argument"

Can someone please help.

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub Creatingquerypivot()
    
        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
        Dim pvt As PivotTable
        Dim StartPvt As String
        Dim SrcData As String
        Dim Pf As PivotField

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
        Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=Sheets("Queries").Name & "!" & Sheets("Queries").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Address)
                 
'Create a new worksheet
        Set sht = Sheets.Add
        sht.Name = "Queries Summary"

'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
        StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1)
        
'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache

        

 - Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
           TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
           TableName:="QueriesSummary")

    
    'To add fields to the pivot table
    
        Set Pf = pvt.PivotFields("Folder")
        Pf.Orientation = xlRowField
           
        Set Pf = pvt.PivotFields("Category")
        Pf.Orientation = xlRowField
            
        Set Pf = pvt.PivotFields("Received")
        Pf.Orientation = xlDataField
```

Comment: I think `TableDestination` expects a `Range` object, not a `String`.

Comment: Replacing String with Range is also not working.

Comment: `"Not working"` is not a helpful description. Can you [edit] your question with the revised code you are using,  and the error message?

Comment: `TableDestination` expects a Variant - does not need to be a Range object, or recorded macros from creating a pivot table would not work - they always use the "range string" apporach.

Answer (score 1):

As BigBen mentioned, `TableDestination` expects a `Range` object.

`Dim StartPvt As Range`

But you'll also need to `Set` it like so:

From:

`StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1)`

To:

`Set StartPvt = sht.Range("A3")`

Comment: `TableDestination` expects a Variant, which can be eiother a string which evaluates to a Range, or an actual Range.

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet names with spaces need to be single-quoted.  It's good practice to always add quotes, even if the name has no spaces: it doesn't harm, and you don't have to worry about fixing your code if you change the sheet name later.

**Edit**: on testing, seems like it only works with R1C1 format range addresses?

```
Set sht = Sheets.Add
sht.Name = "Queries Summary"

StartPvt = "'" & sht.Name & "'!" & sht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

Having said that, you already have Range objects you can use directly without first converting them to string range addresses:

```
    Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=Sheets("Queries").Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
             
    Set sht = Sheets.Add
    sht.Name = "Queries Summary"
    Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=sht.Range("A3"), _
                                        TableName:="QueriesSummary")
```

Comment: There is still an error here:                                                                                             
 StartPvt = "'" & sht.Name & "'!" & sht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)                              Error is Runtime error '91' object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: How have you declared `StartPvt`, and is `sht` set to a worksheet ?  I would drop the "range string" approach and just use the second method where you set the actual range object.

Comment: Yes, Dim StartPvt As Range and Dim sht As Worksheet are already there.

Comment: `StartPvt` is a String, not a Range